# Console to experiment with RoR helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Is there an environment where I can experiment with Rails helpers to create tags? I tried in the rails console but the functions seem not to be defined there. What I want is type this and get the output this would generate in a kind of REPL.

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can't you just try in the views your app generates?

Comment: yes but this is bothersome

Comment: lol! At least you're honest :) I don't know any way to achieve this specifically. We just keep updating the views until it works ;)

Comment: Admit it would be handy to have such a tool instead of looking up what views are generated ...

Comment: Not really a problem for us - we just keep going until what we need is on the screen. Maybe you could ask [@DHH](https://twitter.com/dhh) if you want some specific Rails features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
helper.form_tag("/hello", :method => "get") do
    helper.label_tag(:q, "Search for:")
    helper.text_field_tag(:q)
    helper.submit_tag("Search")
end
```

You can try this out in rails console.